# jQuery to check and uncheck checkboxes only fires once

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a very simple requirement for my jQuery: to check a set of boxes if a radio button is checked, and to clear them all if another is checked.

The jquery works, however it only works once - that is if I click to check them all (all boxes check) and then click to clear them (all boxes clear), and then again click to check them all - there is no effect. Similarly if I manually uncheck some boxes then click to select all again, there is no effect.

**jQuery**

```
$('#all').on('change', function() {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.country').attr('checked', false);   
    } else {
        $('.country').attr('checked', true);
    }
});


$('#none').on('change', function() {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.country').attr('checked', true);    
    } else {
        $('.country').attr('checked', false);
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="subselect">
    <input type="radio" class="TLO" name="radio1" id="all" />Check All
<br />
        <input type="radio" class="TLO" name="radio1" id="none" />Clear All
        <br />
    </div>

    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="cselect" id="countries">
        <input type="checkbox" class="country"  />1
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" class="country"  />2
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" class="country"  />3
    </div>
```

**jsFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/vsGtF/1/

Comment: Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Change your `.attr()` to `.prop()`.

```
$('#all').on('change', function() {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.country').prop('checked', false);   
    } else {
        $('.country').prop('checked', true);
    }
});    
$('#none').on('change', function() {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.country').prop('checked', true);    
    } else {
        $('.country').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vsGtF/3/)**

You could also reduce this to just:

```
$('#all').on('change', function () {
    $('.country').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
$('#none').on('change', function () {
    $('.country').prop('checked', !$(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vsGtF/2/)**

As the docs for [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) state:

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes
>   that have not been set. **To retrieve and change DOM properties such as
>   the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the
>   .prop() method.**

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about prop() I'll read up on it. I'll accept your answer when the time ticks down.

Comment: Just helped me solve this issue as well - would you be able to explain the difference and why one works and the other does not?

Comment: @asfallows- I could try but the jQuery docs already have a thorough explanation: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 4):

I know that this has been duped alot on here but I did miss something, I had:

```
id = $(this).attr('id');
if($('#checkbox_' + id).prop('checked')){
    $('#checkbox_' + id).attr('checked', false);
} else {
    $('#checkbox_' + id).attr('checked', true);
}
```

And as mentioned above **ALL** cases of attr need swapping for prop()

```
if($('#checkbox_' + id).prop('checked')){
    $('#checkbox_' + id).prop('checked', false);
} else {
    $('#checkbox_' + id).prop('checked', true);
}
```

Hope that helps somebody...

Comment: Great! It works for me. Using .prop() works and not attr() in chrome